# javascript to show or hide a class according to a condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In this website : [website](http://79.170.44.120/shivams.com/)

when you scroll down to the badge section,

I have  two conditions for badges :(below are the two badges)

[image: unlocked badge]
[image: locked badge]

Issue :

when the count (which appears on the upper right side of the badge as "10" and "0" here) is greater than "0" then "unlocked with check mark" should be displayed else "locked with cross" should be dispalyed and it should be faded as in hover effect we see normally.

javascript as suggested in the community : (in the fiddle its in the html section with a comment)

```js
$.each($('.Portfolio-box'), function() {
  var count = $(this).children('has-badge').attr('data-count');
  if (data - count > 0) {
    $(this).children('ul.locked').hide();
    $(this).children('ul.unlocked').show();
  } else {
    $(this).children('ul.locked').show();
    $(this).children('ul.unlocked').hide();
  }
});
```

Fiddle link with the html and css.Please Ignore the images or proper alignment.Changes in the "lock and unlock" section of the code works perfect.

Link :https://jsfiddle.net/dkjz1z4k/

Its quite tricky for me.Kindly help,if anyone can.Thanks a lot.God bless.

Comment: The code is correct i believe.but its not working.I meant,in the fiddle,the part I am concerned about is the "lock and unlock" part.any changes works fine in the fiddle.The issue is the above effect I am trying to achieve isnt happening.Thanks a lot. @Paul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost there, just a little tweak at the conditional `if (count > 0)` & `.has-badge`

```
$.each($('.Portfolio-box'), function() {
  var count = $(this).children('.has-badge').attr('data-count');
  if (count > 0) {
    $(this).children('ul.locked').hide();
    $(this).children('ul.unlocked').show();
  } else {
    $(this).children('ul.locked').show();
    $(this).children('ul.unlocked').hide();
  }
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dkjz1z4k/1/)

Comment: thanks for trying.Unfortunately,no luck.I tried.Thanks.God bless

Comment: You had to fix `has-badge` to `.has-badge` also, and change `var data-count` to `var count`

Comment: @jane I just went to his Working Fiddle link and it does work.  There may be other changes he made to your HTML that he didn't represent here.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Works great. @Syden